# Галерея для сайта

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать так чтобы  изображения разного размера в галереи отображались с одинаковой высотой и шириной. То есть чтобы они автоматически обрезались под размер.[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

Изображение 1 имеет в оригинале один размер а изображение 2 другой но при этом они корректно, не растянуто отображаются на странице.

Answer (score 2):

Решением является указать способ заполнения объекта.

Если вы используете `<div>` с указанием фонового изображения:

- `background-size: cover` - залить, без пустого пространства
- `background-size: contain` - уместить, появятся пустые пространства *([экранное каше](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5))*

Если вы используете тег `<img>` то следует использовать аналогичные CSS-свойства:

- `object-fit: cover` - залить, без пустого пространства
- `object-fit: contain` - уместить, появятся пустые пространства *([экранное каше](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5))*

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать этот плагин: https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

```
var basic = $('#demo-basic').croppie({
    viewport: {
        width: 150,
        height: 200
    }
});
```

Comment: Можно, но наверняка есть решение "из коробки" так сказать =)

Answer (score 0):

Для этих целей можно использовать такую конструкцию:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.gallery {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}
.img {
  width: 33.3333%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/27/13/16/cat-694730__340.jpg)"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/05/07/06/44/animal-339400__340.jpg)"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/01/10/46/cat-468232__340.jpg)"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/13/14/34/cat-1977416__340.jpg)"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/13/22/10/cat-1978356__340.jpg)"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/13/10/08/cat-2062223__340.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

То есть, размещать изображение как `background` в блоке с `background-size: cover`.