# LightSlider как выровнять контент?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, библиотеки

Добрый день уважаемые. Подскажите пожалуйста, как добиться что б данный слайдер обрезал все слайды по одной высоте, в независимости от размеров фото (вертикальные или горизонтальные кадры)? 
Читал эту документацию и пока не нашел http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/
Мой код

```js
window.onload = function () {


    $(".box-sliderOne__items").lightSlider({
        item: 3,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        loop: true,
        controls: true,
        // thumbItem:0,
        gallery: true,
        thumbMargin: 2,
        onSliderLoad: function(el) {
            el.lightGallery();
        }

    });
 };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При уменьшении экрана проблема остается 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для полноты картины исходники тут https://github.com/BlackStar1991/gbo 
Фаил index.html styles/main.scss

Comment: Что-то не совсем понятно, вы хотите вписать изображения в блок определенной высоты и ширины или выстраивать карусель с фото разной ориентации, но одной высоты? Так же, ваши исходники было бы лучше загрузить на [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/), [Codepen](http://codepen.io/) или еще куда-нить. Прикрепленные фото не открываются.

Comment: Я бы вам рекомендовал посмотреть на Variable Width у [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). Настраивается элементарно, примеров много.

Answer (score 1):

блоку в котором находится фото задать определенную высоту и ширину(фиксированную), я не посмотрел исходники, но если картинки в теге img , то лучше использовать

div {background-image},

так как это лучше если у вас картинки разных размеров, при этом задать блоку

{background-size:cover;},

так картинка более внятно и красиво будет выглядеть, если не хотите ничего менять просто задайте фиксированную высоту блоку в котором сама картинка. если картинка очень нестандартная,

{background-size:cover;}

поможет ее более или менее ее красиво вставит в блок. при этом, если есть потребность, при нестандартной картинке, какой-нить определенный кусочек картинки который скрылся из виду тут вам в помощь

{background-position: значение , значение;}

Comment: Спасибо, ваш метод с background-size:cover Отчасти помог. Код тут https://jsfiddle.net/1rzrbsav/ Но теперь возникла следующая проблема, при уменьшении экрана снова вылазят те фото что не надо

Comment: Думаю, имелось ввиду задать высоту, ширину и фон для пункта списка, а не размещать в нем `<img>`. [Тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629091/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0/629111#629111) есть ответ на вопрос о том, как сделать блоки одинаковой высоты и ширины.

Answer (score 0):

Каждое изображение вы можете обернуть в див, которому зададите фиксированную высоту и обрезание изображения внутри него:

```
div{
  position:relative;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, пока что ваш совет не помог https://jsfiddle.net/1rzrbsav/1/ При уменьшении экрана <760px вылазит "паразитная" (вертикально ориентированная) фотка

Answer (score 0):

Вот держите идеальный пример не только для слайдера, но и для любых элементов, где нужно контролировать размер изображения его родителем.
В этом коде ".image-slide" отвечает за один из ваших слайдов, а ".tipo-image" изображение.
Я сделал высоту изображения выше родителя, что бы вы поняли как формируется изображение внутри родителя, а также закомментировал "overflow:hidden, который вы должны будете вписать. Закомментировал чтобы вы видели размер изображения и в какие стороны он выходит за грань слайда.
Так вот задав родителю "display: flex, justify-content: center; align-items: center" я центрировал изображение, что бы выступающие за границу родителя части изображения обрезались равномерно, а не всё снизу например, так как обычно в центре картинки самое главное расположено)).
Ну и напоследок картинке задаются "width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;"(сейчас width и height стоят 500px и 250px, у вас же само изображение будет задавать свои исходные размеры), что бы не важно в высоту идёт картинка или в ширину, она достигала всегда краёв родителя и object-fit её растягивал по меньшей стороне, но при этом большую сторону не сплющивал. Можете даже по экспериментировать и убрать у картинки object-fit, увидите что она сплющится, что бы поместиться в окно родителя).

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.image-slide {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: green;
  // overflow: hidden;
}
.tipo-image {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-slide">
  <div class="tipo-image"></div>
</div>
```